# Importing a Vue component fails with error "the requested module does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vue.js

I have an ASP.Net Core application and I am trying to add some Vue.js components to it.
I did a proof of concept without a build step where I created a non-SFC component (with inline template), added the CDN Vue library to my app and this just worked:

```
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module">
       import { createApp } from 'vue';
       import MyComponent from '../js/Vue/my-component.js?v=@version';
       createApp(MyComponent).mount('#app');
   </script>
```

Now I want to move to SFC format and a build step.
I used Vite to scaffold a new Vue app as a subdirectory of my app.
The intention is to build this first and copy its compiled output to the parent app, then import more or less as before.

I am trying this with the HelloWorld component from the default scaffolded app.
I changed the vite.config.js so that it just outputs the HelloWorld component:

```
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    minify: false,
    outDir: '../wwwroot/js/Vue', // this is within the parent app
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        helloWorld: resolve(__dirname, 'src/HelloWorld/index.html')
      }, 
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/js/[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/js/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[ext]/[name].[ext]`,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Then within a page in the parent app I do something like this:

```
    <div id="helloWorld"></div>
    
    <script type="module">
        import { createApp } from 'vue';
        import HelloWorld from '../js/Vue/assets/js/helloWorld.js?v=@version';
    
        createApp(HelloWorld).mount('#helloWorld');
    
    </script>
```

....
as well as:

```
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

and

When this line executes:

```
import HelloWorld from '../js/Vue/assets/js/helloWorld.js?v=@version';
```

the result is an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../js/Vue/assets/js/helloWorld.js?v=xxx' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error message was that this line

```
import HelloWorld from '../js/Vue/assets/js/helloWorld.js?v=@version';
```

was expecting a default export, and none was found.
I tried

```
import { HelloWorld } from '../js/Vue/assets/js/helloWorld.js?v=@version';
```

but this named export was also not found.

I finally resolved this by publishing the "child" app as a library.
I still don't know why the original method did not result in any exported module.